# Не записываются данные в БД из текстового файла

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема. Считываю текстовый файл, данные которого необходимо записать в БД. Компилятор ошибок не выдает, но записи не создаются в БД.

```
String userName = "root";
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String userPassword = "root";
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,userName,userPassword)) {
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    /*
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("D:\\1\\1\\1.txt")))) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            countRows++;
        }
    }*/

    System.out.println("CountRows "+countRows);

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("D:\\1\\1\\1.txt")))) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            strArray = line.split(Pattern.quote("||"));//Тут нормально работает сплит!!!!!!!

            String[] dd = strArray[0].split(Pattern.quote("||"));
            String d1 = dd[2]+"-"+dd[1]+"-"+dd[0];
            st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO somedata (random_date, random_latin_characters, random_cyrilic_characters, random_number, random_double) VALUES (\'"+ d1 +"\',\'"+ strArray[1]+"\',\'"+ strArray[2]+"\',\'"+ strArray[3]+"\',\'"+ strArray[4]+"\')");
            //st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO somedata(random_date, random_latin_characters, random_cyrilic_characters, random_number, random_double) VALUES('01.01.2017','sdfsd','ыавыаыв',1233212,0.32432)");


            System.out.format("Осталось записей: %d\tЗаписано в БД: %d\tВыполнено: %.2f",countRows--, countAdded++, countAdded/countRows*100);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

} catch (Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: зачем вам ssl на localhost? и почему вы игнорируете инстанс класса "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"?

Comment: По моему, вы просто забыли `commit` сделать после вставки.